# rangeOrOdd - Return 1 if an input number is in a range and/or odd

Tags: java

I am trying to solve this : Given an integer, return 1 if the number is between -5 and 5 exclusive and/or if it is an odd integer. If neither properties apply, return 0.
Here is what I have tried:

```
int rangeOrOdd(int val) {
if (val < 5)
    return 1;

    else if (val > 5)
        return 1;
    else if ((val%2)!=0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 0;
```

}

Comment: And the problem is ...?

Comment: I think you forgot the '-' in "else if (val > 5)" and you have to give 1 after "else if ((val%2)!=0)" instead of 0

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are checking the different conditions individually.  For instance, as soon as your number is smaller than `5`, you return `1`, which is wrong, because you would then return `1` for numbers like `-1000`.

Also, you are returning `0` for an odd number. You were supposed to return `1` in that case.

You have to combine your conditions using ANDs (`&&`) and ORs (`||`).

Here is a one liner that combines the different conditions correctly:

```
return ((val < 5 && val > -5) || val % 2 == 1) ? 1 : 0;
```

And if you don't like it in one line, you can always split it like this (but it's the same thing):

```
if ((val < 5 && val > -5) || val % 2 == 1) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wait, what? Who's crying? :)